# Parameters for using a boolean

Tags: java, algorithm, boolean

I am struggeling to understand when i should use a boolean. What are good parameters to recognize when a boolean should be a good thing to use? For example in the Odd-Even sort algorithm the boolean makes the whole algorithm work.

```
long[] a = {7,5,8,2,4,1,9,3,5,6};
int nElems = 10;

public void oddEvenSort() {
    boolean sorted = false;
    while (!sorted) {
        sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < nElems - 1; i += 2) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                swap(i, i + 1);
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < nElems - 1; j += 2) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                swap(j, j + 1);
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But where is the point in time that determines that a boolean should/could be used? Compared to other simple sorting algorithms, where you can decrement or increment an index for values sorted, this algorithm doesn't have that. Are there any rules or guide lines i can follow to understand the usage of a boolean better? This isn't just limited to this algorithm, that is just an example.

Comment: If you only want 2 possible values, then use a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

It should be used when there are two states of a variable. In your case it's rather simple, the algorithm can be sorted or unsorted hence it's good to use a boolean.

Also, in Depth First Search for example, a node can be visited or not-visited.

Another example is in graphs where edges can go from one node to another and back you need to keep track whether you processed a node or not. A boolean is a perfect match for that case.

Comment: What would be the trick to recognize these two states, given you have a blank piece of paper and no code yet? I get it, look for those states i guess.

Comment: Logical thinking. You model real world problems using common sense and logic. We know that the node can be visited or not (2 states). Are you gonna use `int` which can store 2^32 states (4 bytes, theoretical*) or just a simple `boolean` (1 bit, theoretical*)? *theoretical - it could be that the JVM uses more space to represent a variable but that is out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit broad; generally speaking, a `boolean` should be used when it has to be stated whether some condition is the case or not; I hope I understood your question right.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately whatever you put in a `while` loop, `for` loop or `if`-`else` condition, will come down to a boolean value. `while (i < 10)`, `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`, `if (i == 10)`. `boolean` is always almost indispensible with conditional checkers.

Answer (score 0):

A boolean value should be used when you have a true/false value that never holds anything other than true or false.

Does a car have wheels? True or False, boolean.

How many wheels does a car have? 3 or 4: integer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a boolean here and it doesn't appear to do what you want.  I would assume you want to swap odd entries with other odd entries.

```
public void oddEvenSort() {
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nElems - 2; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 2]) {
                swap(i, i + 2);
                continue;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For sorting an array from low to high.

Comment: @Xbit how does the odd even come into it? it appears to be a bubble sort done in a complicated way.

Comment: the idea that this is handy in a multiprocessing environment, because the odd or even pairs are independant of eachother, so they can be checked and swapped if necessary by a different processor. I don't know, it's an asignment from a book. Got the general idea from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort

Comment: @Xbit I read the page but I don't see how this helps multi-threading. You need independent processing esp of separate cache line, to efficiently process data.

Answer (score 0):

In java all conditions are evaluated to a `boolean` value, so even if you don't declare it explicitly, you are using a `boolean` value. Now, when a `boolean` variable is necessary, depends for what you are using it.

In the sorting algorithm above, it's used as a flag to see if further sorting is necessary. You assume the array is sorted and after that you mark it as false if it's not and you made a swap between 2 values.

Leaving the example, another place when it's useful to use a `boolean` value if when you have an overly long condition and you wish to make the code more readable.

Sometimes you simply use it for when you have only 2 possible states for a variable (like on/off) and you don't want to create an enum or constant for the state.